# Help in debugging VF Email template

Tags: vf-email-template

I have a VF email template created that uses a VF component with attribute URLType which gets the value dynamically on Email  from the controller for a community URL(External) and salesforce URL (Internal). But for some reason its bypassing the  condition in my controller and directing only to External value even I have the URLType= "Internal" in my email template, I am not able to debug the issue. Can someone help me with this

Here is mail template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate >
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >  
 <VFcomponent id1="{!relatedTo.Id}" URLType1 ="External"/>
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

VF component:

```
<apex:component controller="compoentcontroller" access="global">

    <apex:attribute type="string" name="id1"  id="id" assignTo="{!id}"/>
    <apex:attribute type="string" name="URLType1"  id="URLType" assignTo="{!URLType}"/>

  Please click here to proceed further {!baseurl.URL__c}/{!id}

</apex:component>
```

Apex controller:

```
public with sharing class compoentcontroller {

   public  customsetting__c baseurl {get;set;}
   public Id id {get;set;}
   public string URLType {get;set;}

   public compoentcontroller ( ) {
       system.debug('URLTYPE!!!!!!'+URLType);
      if(URLType == 'External'){
         baseurl = customsetting__c.getValues('External'); 
      } 
      Else {     
       baseurl = customsetting__c.getValues('Internal'); 
       }
       system.debug('baseurl@@@@@'+baseurl);
      }


}
```